# Property on homomorphism between finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I was reading some lecture notes on homomorphism between finite groups and intuitively it appeared to me that for a $\phi$ an homomorphism $G \rightarrow H$, we should have:

$$|\,\textrm{Im}(\phi)\,| =  \frac{|\,G\,|}{|\,\textrm{ker}(\phi)\,|}$$

where $| . |$ stands for order. Is this right? If yes, is there a short demonstration for?

Comment: Try "the First Isomorphism Theorem" (for groups, of course), and Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Yes, the fibers of the map $\phi$ partition $G$ into subsets of size $\lvert \ker(\phi)\lvert $ (these happen to be the cosets of the kernel).

Comment: What possible reason is there for downvoting this question? It boggles my mind that someone did.

Comment: @stochasm yes! thank you for introducing cosets here, it makes it so much relevant and clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Recall that that given a group homomorphism $\phi \colon G \to G'$, $\ker \phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. The first isomorphism theorem states that given such a homomorphism, there is an isomorphism $G / \ker \phi \cong \text{Im} \phi$. This gives your result. A proof can be found in any elementary book on Abstract Algebra, or by simply Googling it.

Answer (score 1):

ker($\phi$) is a normal subgroup of G, so G/ker($\phi$) is well defined and |G/ker($\phi$)|=|G|/|ker($\phi$)|.
Thanks to "the first isomorphism theorem", there exists an isomorphism between Im($\phi$) and G/Ker($\phi$) moreover |Im($\phi$)|=|G|/|Ker($\phi$)|